# In Rails 3.1, how should I format ActiveRecord association declarations for a model with lots of them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

In my Rails 3.1 project, I have some models with lots of associations. Using ActiveRecord association declarations, I end up with model files that look like this:

```
# app/models/some_model.rb

class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :other_model
  has_many :more_models
  has_many :yet_more_models, :through => :more_models
  has_one :another_model, :dependent => :destroy

  # ... these declarations continue,
  # and continue,
  # and continue,
  # all the way down to line 32
end
```

This quickly becomes exceedingly ugly and dampens my comprehension/motivation/happiness. What can I do to mitigate?

- **[a]** Format/group/indent them in a particular way?
- **[b]** Re-think my data model, as this may be a symptom of poor design
- **[c]** Live with it -- everyone's model files look this way.

Comment: Can you give an example of what kinds of resources these are? 32 associations in one model seems absurd, I've never seen anything like that!

Comment: [b] there is clearly something wrong with your model if you have that many associations.

Comment: @AshleyWilliams -- One such resource is 'Book', which has_many :authors, :languages, :genres, :categories, :subjects, :translators, :tags, :identifiers, :reviews ... plus others specific to this application, and their :through associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is to align related assignments vertically.  That carries through to related declarations too.

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :other_model
  has_many   :more_models
  has_many   :yet_more_models, :through => :more_models
  has_one    :another_model,   :dependent => :destroy
end
```

If you think this is verbose, you haven't seen DataMapper models :P

Answer (score 1):

is it possible to group them, by different aspects / functionality of your `SomeModel` ? do these group of associations tend to have quite a lot of accompanying methods in your `SomeModel` class? if so, dividing your model into a few modules (like traits), one for every aspect, bundling everything including class methods and association declarations, may help.

e.g.

```
class SomeModel
  include SomeModel::ThisBehavior
  include SomeModel::ThatFeature
end
```

and

```
module SomeModel::ThisBehavior
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :this
    has_many :that
    belongs_to :those

    attr_protected :a, :b
    attr_accessor :c, :d
  end

  def do_this
  end

  ...

  module ClassMethods
    ...
  end
end
```

The next step could be trying to make those modules quite agnostic, and group your tests accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a model with lots of associations and it's fine for me. If there is a complex logic behind, it will result on a complex bunch of associations. For example, I have an Account class that has over 60 associations: users, companies, centers, products, documents, routes, vehicles .....

This question is more about readability. First of all, decide a convention and follow the same rule all over the project (belongs_to first, has_one second, has_many third, habtm last)
Second advice: If some relations are clearly related with a well separated functionality, you can split your class into some modules keeping each relation in the modules it concerns. But this is a general rule.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Account::CRM
  include Account::Plans
  include Account::Finances      

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can distribute parent models into others...

Example, I have an app that uses three different instances of User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :social_profile
    has_one :tasks_profile
    has_one :bank_account
end
```

And other models that represents user in other project scopes:

```
class SocialProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :many_things
    ...
end
```

Same for `TasksProfile` and `BankAccount`.